# Safari on OSX renders margin-top strangely

Tags: html, css, macos, layout, safari

I have a strange behaviour on Safari on OSX machines. All parents seems to inherit the child's margin-top:

[image]

The parent has the same spacing to top:

[image]

This leads to a space on top of the page.

This only happens on Safari / OSX, mobile Safari hasn't got problems, FF or Chrome on OSX neither.

Thank you in advance

Comment: where is your code

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot link to the site due to private data. But I found a solution / hack and will answer this. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding a div with line-height of 0px:

```
<div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content="">
        <div class="safarifix" style="line-height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

it seems that this changes the status of off-canvas-content to have it's own positioning. Fact is, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

I have found safari adds unwanted margin/spacing to my web pages. The best thing to do is put this at the top of your style sheet:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

this will tell browser to reset any browser styles on padding and margin.